# Angular - using Renderer2 inside the constructor of a directive

Tags: angular

I want to migrate an Angular app to a higher version and one the steps is to replace `Renderer` with `Renderer2`, and I have a problem because `Renderer2` seems to be not defined inside the constructor:

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
    renderer.setAttribute(el.nativeElement, "data-id", this.uniqueId);
}
```

So I get an error which says:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined

Do I have to move `renderer.setAttribute(...)` into OnInit or something like that? With `Renderer` this worked fine, but with `Renderer2` it no longer works.

Current Angular version: 5.2.10

Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I add do this on `ngAfterViewInit`. That means after first render!

*I would also check explicit If the element is already initialized and maybe add a retry policy.
`if(el)el.nativeElement...`
(If your element is inside a `*ngIf` directive).*

Comment: Thanks for your response! But is it not possible to use `Renderer` inside the constructor?

Comment: No, the elements are undefined. Also, it is bad practice to write code in constructor, especially when you have all this beautiful hooks like `ngOnInit` etc.

Comment: Not yet, I will try it. Thanks!